# NSMutableDictionary with two keys pointing to same object causing "double free" exception

Tags: ios, exception, malloc, nsmutabledictionary

So I'm trying to make a dictionary with objects that each have two keys pointing to them. I have written this block to set the objects:

```
ALAssetsGroupEnumerationResultsBlock resultsBlock = ^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop)
    {
        if(result)
        {
            NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathWithGroupIndex:groupIndex andAssetIndex:index];

            [assetsDictionary setObject:result forKey:path];
            [assetsDictionary setObject:result forKey:result.defaultRepresentation.url];
        }
    };
```

That is causing this exception:

> malloc: *** error for object 0x1f8c1200: pointer being freed was not allocated

Any thoughts on how to fix this problem, or a better way to implement a dictionary this way?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with putting the same object into the same dictionary under multiple keys. Given that it doesn't seem like the code you're showing would be at fault. What evidence do you have that setting the result in the dictionary is the culprit?

Comment: When an object is put in a dictionary, its retained, and when the dictionary is released, so is the object. So they are balanced. Some other object is over releasing it, its just when the dictionary does the release that you discover it.

Comment: You guys are totally right. The problem was actually that the assetsDictionary was being done in an NSOperationBlock and there were 10 blocks going concurrently, so I think it was due to mutating the contents on different threads at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out, it was not what I thought at all. The problem was due to mutating the dictionary's contents on different threads at the same time